# When should a question be tagged "usability"?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, ia

We have 198 questions tagged [usability](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usability). It's currently defined as "the ease of use and learnability of a human-made object," which could apply to just about every question on UX. Is there a way to define "usability" so that it would apply to less than 10% of the questions?

If not, please join me in retagging [usability](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/usability) questions -- removing the tag and also evaluating whether other tags on the question should be added or removed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than do this manually, I can click the magic button to remove the tag.

Should I do that?

edit: this tag was burninated. There might be some [untagged](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/untagged) questions now.

[image: this tag has been BURNINATED]

Comment: Sure, go ahead and nuke it.

Comment: @patrick ok that is done; take a look at the untagged questions now.

Answer (score 2):

Just to be sure I've looked up some definitions outside SE, but to me it confirms that this tag is too broad here, indeed almost every question would fit (at least too much to be of any use). Ergo, **I'm up for removing / retagging**.

Comment: I was going to say that it could easily be defined to something narrow enough, but since most people wouldn't really differentiate what is and what isn't usability (as the tagging here shows), I agree with you completely.

Comment: @Charles I was thinking if we can come up with a narrow definition we can put it in the tag wiki and try to enforce it.