# Alternatives to the "best-practices" tag

Tags: discussion, tags, ia

After [usability](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/q/301/61), next on my hit-list is [best-practices](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/best-practices). I think it's too generic to be useful, and we should encourage more specific tags like [research](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research) and [design-patterns](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/design-patterns). What do you think? What other tags capture the idea of "best practices" but are more specific?

Or if you think we should keep best-practices, how can we define it so that retaggers have clear guidance on when it should be used?

Comment: I winced when I first saw the tag here, but it's grown on me to a certain extent. Will have to get thinking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that is exactly the tag we killed on Stack Overflow in the Great Meta-Tag Purge..

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/

I can't see it being any different here.

Comment: Please kill **best-practices** and **design**. That should take care of the worst-offending meta tags. Thanks!

Comment: @patrick this is done; look out for [untagged] questions.

Comment: Weird. You took out [best-practices] but now its back under the name [best-practice]. Can you kill that one too?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can be killed. Even though I just used it. :) But when I think about the term it feels like the whole UX universe is built around finding the best possible solution. And I suppose it can't be replaced.